# Preventing serialization of properties in servicestack RedisClient

Tags: redis, servicestack

I think title is clear. ServiceStack Redis Client serializes(stores) Get Only Properties (also I added ReadOnly attribute).

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's expected behaviour: if its readable it will be serialized, and if its writable its deserializable. i.e. It will serialize **get only** properties but wont serialize **set only** public properties.

ServiceStack serializers does support the [IgnoreDataMember] attribute ignoring properties, see [this example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/DataContractTests.cs#L36).

Comment: I have to clear all X instance from Redis Db for testing. But I could not find redisClient.As<X>().CLEAR() method? How can I clear all X instance?

Comment: Comments on answers are to add clarification to existing answers not to ask new un-related questions. Ask a new properly-worded question if you want answers for something else.

Comment: You are correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790385/how-can-i-clear-all-instances-of-type-x-in-servicestack-redis-client