# How can I clear all Instances of type X in ServiceStack Redis Client

Tags: redis, servicestack

I want to clear all X instance from Redis Db for testing. But I could not find redisClient.As().CLEAR() method? How can I clear all X instance?

I can add X Instances using

```
var client=new PooledRedisClientManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisServer"]).GetClient();
X x=new X();
client.As<X>().Store(x);
```

all x instances are added to Db as urn:X:x.id pattern.

Comment: Do you mean clear all items in a specific key?

Comment: I've added extra info to question eyossi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IRedisTypedClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/Generic/IRedisTypedClient.cs#L21) implements the generic [IBasicPersistenceProvider<T>](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/DataAccess/IBasicPersistenceProvider.Generic.cs#L30) interface which has a `DeleteAll()` method. So what you're after is simply:

```
client.As<T>().DeleteAll();
```

For more fine-grained deletion options you also have:

```
client.As<T>().DeleteById(id);
client.As<T>().DeleteByIds(ids);
```

Comment: DeleteAll does not work. I'm getting weird {"wrong number of arguments for 'del' command, sPort: 19570, LastCommand: "} error. I'm using Windows 32 and x64 port of Redis server, client and utils. redis-2.4.5-win32-win64. OS is Win 7 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: DeleteAll works for me https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Generic/RedisPersistenceProviderTestsBase.cs#L80 if you found issues can you submit a gist/pull-request of a stand-alone failing unit test that exhibits the issue

Comment: What is your redis server configuration for this test? (linux based, windows based vs.)

Comment: It shouldn't matter, Tests works against both Linux and Windows redis-server builds.

Comment: You have to make sure there's something to delete before calling DeleteAll().  Just an oddity of the API.

Comment: That's a bug you shouldn't have to care about state like this when using the RedisClient. I've fixed it in https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/commit/1aaca5d76d7ee9a741f41b001119eb50a9f063f1 available in next release from v3.9.12+

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the RedisNativeClient class you have this method to delete a specific key:

```
 public int Del(string key)
```

if you want to delete all keys you can call Del with * as key

and you have those methods as well:

```
 public void FlushDb()
 public void FlushAll()
```

if you are using the RedisClient class you have this method:

```
 public bool Remove(string key) // Again i guess you can use the * for delete all keys
```

Answer (score 0):

client.As().DeleteAll();

I think naming "Remove" is for relations.

User.Cars.Remove("Red Car")

If you want to delete object "Delete" :)

Delete("Red Car")

It does not work. I'm getting weird {"wrong number of arguments for 'del' command, sPort: 19570, LastCommand: "} error.